# SQL Count Distinct Rows

Tags: sql, distinct

Having the following table.

```
Date    Direction   Market  Time
    10/17/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00
    10/18/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00
    10/19/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00
    10/20/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00
    10/21/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00
    10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  23:20:00
    10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00
    10/24/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00
    10/25/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00
    10/26/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00
    10/27/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00
    10/28/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00
```

I would like to count distinct rows in a different column but assign a number sequentially to the repeated rows (from 1..n)

```
    Date    Direction   Market  Time   Count
10/17/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/18/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/19/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/20/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/21/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  23:20:00    1
10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    2
10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  23:30:00    3
10/25/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
10/26/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
10/27/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
10/28/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
```

So in this case only the 10/23/2016 has 3 different values. So assign 1 to the first occurrence, 2 to the second, etc.

I tried the following

```
select 
        departureDate,
DIRECTION, LEG,  SCHD_LEG_DEP_TM, count(SCHD_LEG_DEP_TM) over (partition by departureDate)
 from table3mirs mirs 
        INNER JOIN sys_calendar.calendar
        ON calendar_date = mirs.departureDate

 where leg='GRUJFK'
 group by 1,2,3,4
```

but get

```
    Date    Direction   Market  Time   Count
10/17/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/18/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/19/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/20/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/21/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:05:00    1
10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  23:20:00    3
10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    3
10/23/2016  SB  GRUJFK  23:30:00    3
10/25/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
10/26/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
10/27/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
10/28/2016  SB  GRUJFK  22:30:00    1
```

Any idea?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSSQL (I think you might be given the partition by), you can try this.

```
select 
        departureDate,
DIRECTION, LEG,  SCHD_LEG_DEP_TM, count(DISTINCT SCHD_LEG_DEP_TM) over (partition by departureDate)
 from table3mirs mirs 
        INNER JOIN sys_calendar.calendar
        ON calendar_date = mirs.departureDate

 where leg='GRUJFK'
 group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't use count distinct in a window function. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89031/using-distinct-in-window-function-with-over

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're just needing row_number..

```
SELECT  departureDate ,
        DIRECTION ,
        LEG ,
        SCHD_LEG_DEP_TM ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY departureDate ORDER BY SCHD_LEG_DEP_TM )
FROM    table3mirs mirs
        INNER JOIN sys_calendar.calendar ON calendar_date = mirs.departureDate
WHERE   leg = 'GRUJFK'
GROUP BY 1 ,
        2 ,
        3 ,
        4
```